# Compile Vuetify tags/template received as prop in runtime

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I want to send a 'template' prop to a component then render it. If I send a plain HTML it works, but if I send a Vuetify tag like `<v-btn>test</v-btn>` the template does not get compiled.

I know i shouldn't pass a template via props, but this is a specific case: The parent component works as a "template builder" and the child components works as the "result viewer", so I have to pass the created template to the child so that it can compile and show it.

Here's what I've been trying:

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
// Some imports here ...
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify';

new Vue({
    vuetify,
    render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

App.vue

```
<script>

import Vue from 'vue'

// eslint-disable-next-line
var staticRenderFns = [];

var dynamic = {
  props: ['template'],
  data: () => ({
      templateRender: null,
  }),
  render(h) {
    if (!this.templateRender) {
      return h('div', 'loading...');
    } else { // If there is a template, I'll show it
      return this.templateRender();
    }
  },
  watch: {
    // Every time the template prop changes, I recompile it to update the DOM
    template:{
      immediate: true, // makes the watcher fire on first render, too.
      handler() {
        var res = Vue.compile(this.template);

        this.templateRender = res.render;
        
        // staticRenderFns belong into $options, 
        // appearantly
        this.$options.staticRenderFns = []
        
        // clean the cache of static elements
        // this is a cache with the results from the staticRenderFns
        this._staticTrees = []
        
        // Fill it with the new staticRenderFns
        for (var i in res.staticRenderFns) {
          //staticRenderFns.push(res.staticRenderFns[i]);
          this.$options.staticRenderFns.push(res.staticRenderFns[i])
        }
      }
    }
  },
}

export default {
  name: 'App',
  data: () => ({
    template:`
            <v-row>
              <v-col>
                <v-btn class="pa-2 primary white--text">Test</v-btn>
              </v-col>
              <v-col>
                <v-btn class="pa-2 primary white--text">Test</v-btn>
              </v-col>
              <v-col>
                <v-btn class="pa-2 primary white--text">Test</v-btn>
              </v-col>
            </v-row>
    `,
  }),
  components:{
    dynamic,
  },
};
</script>
<template>
  <v-app id="app" style="padding-top: 64px;">
    <v-app-bar
      app
      color="blue"
    >
      <v-btn depressed color="white" class="black--text" click="addBtn">Button</v-btn>
    </v-app-bar>

    <dynamic :template='template'></dynamic>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the dynamic component try to render a vue component using the passed template :

```
var dynamic = {
  props: ['template'],
  data: () => ({
      templateRender: null,
  }),
  render(h) {
    if (!this.template) {
      return h('div', 'loading...');
    } else { // If there is a template, I'll show it
      return h(Vue.component('dynamic-render', {template:this.template}));
    }
  },
}
```

**Full Example**

```js
var dynamic = {
  props: ['template'],
  data: () => ({
    templateRender: null,
  }),
  render(h) {
    if (!this.template) {
      return h('div', 'loading...');
    } else { // If there is a template, I'll show it
      return h(Vue.component('dynamic-render', {
        template: this.template
      }));
    }
  },
}

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    count: 1,
    template: `
            <v-row>
              <v-col>
                <v-btn class="pa-2 primary white--text">Test</v-btn>
              </v-col>
              <v-col>
                <v-btn class="pa-2 primary white--text">Test</v-btn>
              </v-col>
              <v-col>
                <v-btn class="pa-2 primary white--text">Test</v-btn>
              </v-col>
            </v-row>
    `,
  }),
  components: {
    dynamic,
  },
  methods: {
    changeContent() {
      this.count = this.count + 1
      this.template = '';
      setTimeout(() => { //simulate loading status
        this.template = `<v-col>
                <v-btn class="pa-2 primary white--text">Btn ${this.count}</v-btn>
              </v-col>`
      }, 2000);

    }
  }


})
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-btn depressed color="primary" class="black--text" @click="changeContent">change content</v-btn>
    <dynamic :template='template'></dynamic>


  </v-app>
</div>
```