# JSON data button click is not working in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54090325/vue-js-print-raw-html-and-call-component-methods) Question but here no approach shown.

```
"element": [
  {
   "value": "<button @click='changeTheme()' class='theme-link btn btn-light'>Default</button>",
   "class": "text-success"
  }
]
```

I have bind the JSON data with Vue Component like the below:

```
<p v-else v-html="element[0].value"></p>
```

Now, I am trying to call this method. But it's not firing!

```
methods: {
  changeTheme() {
     alert("Y");
  }
}
```

Comment: I saw the Question but here no approach shown. I have no option to save data in database.

Comment: there's only an approach to render the vue component, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63078290/compile-vuetify-tags-template-received-as-prop-in-runtime/63079193#63079193) but if you apply it here will not recognize the methods since the methods are defined in parent component

Comment: There is no way to solve this with my approach? If I use method in JSON then?

Comment: it's complicated, you could use the approach that i mentioned in the comment above but you should also find a way to pass events and data to the dynamic component

Answer (score 0):

Maybe separate the action from the button by putting it on the object on a different key, and calling it on click of the element:

```
"element": [
  {
   "value": "<button class='theme-link btn btn-light'>Default</button>",
   "class": "text-success",
   "action": function () {alert("Y")}
  }
]
```

```
<p v-else v-html="element[0].value" @click="element[0].action"></p>
```